# .length returns (NoMethodError) ruby version 2.7.0p0

Tags: ruby

hello im trying to run this code but i receive the no method error on my .length line of code i asume is some kind of ruby version issue but how can i fix this?

```
class BookCase

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      @capacity = attributes[:capacity] 
      @books = attributes[:books] || []
    end

    def full?
      space = @books.length
      puts space
    end
end

bookcase1 = BookCase.new(capacity: 4, books: 6)
puts "is it full?"
bookcase1.full?
```

Output: `undefined method` length' for 6:Integer (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Take another look at the error - there is no `length` method for an `integer`.

Comment: You can change your `@books` variable to `@books = attributes[:books] || 0`. Then you won’t need to call `.length` in your `full?` method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you´re trying to do, but the problem has nothing to do with the Ruby version. The value of the instance variable `books` is the `Integer` number 6, and there is no method or attribute `length` in the `Integer` class.